# import-csv, add column1, set header, populate, export-csv

Tags: csv, powershell, import, export

I have a csv with 5 columns and their headers.
I have to get contents
Add a column and place it 1st of all.
Name Header, populate with same word.
Export to file.

I need a powershell script for that
what I have tried so far

```
$temp=gc "file1.csv"
$OS = "OOSS"
$array=@()
$temp | Foreach{
    $elements=$_.split(";")
    $array+= ,@($elements[0],$elements[1],$elements[2],$elements[3],$elements[4])
}

foreach ($value in $array)
{
   write-host "$OS" ";"$value[0]";"$value[1]";"$value[2]";"$value[3]";"$value[4]";"
} out-file "file2.csv"
```

Comment: Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38371239/edit) rather than posting code in comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write-Host` writes directly to the host (the console), and so that won't help you.

The easiest way to "add a column" is probably by using `Select-Object` with a single calculated property and then `*` to select the existing properties.

Finally, write it back to disk with `Export-Csv`:

```
Import-Csv .\file1.csv |Select-Object @{Label="NewColumn";Expression={"Value"}},* |Export-Csv .\file2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```